# raspberry pi wont show the desktop

Tags: desktop, pi-400

my raspberry pi 400 does not show the desktop even after reflashing the sd card. the ttys work fine. when i reflash the sd card the setup page will shw and i will be able to set it up and reboot. when i reboot it works as expected. then when i turn it off i will see the rainbow screen, then the spash screen for about 2 seconds and then the screen goes dark. when i turn the tv on and off i am able to press ctrl alt and f1 and see the tty. sometimes i can use startx from there but more often than not it does not work. if i turn the pi on when the sd card is not inserted i get the bootloader screen. i have tried other operating systems and installing raspberry pi os with pinn but they all only will work once.

EDIT: i tried to connect to it using vnc and that gave me a black screen.

Comment: I assume you are using the latest Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye, my guess would be the latest video drivers don't like your screen. Have you got another screen you can try? A work around might be change from kms to fkms driver in /boot/config.txt

Comment: CoderMike then why wont vnc work when i try to connect?

Comment: You probably need to set the 'VNC resolution' in raspi-config.

Comment: I had a similar black screen via vnc. That happend when I changed some Linux configs trying to experiment. I had to install a fresh raspberry pi OS after this to make it work

Comment: codermike, i did that and vnc works flawlessly